# IMAP fetch command incomplete response

Tags: c, email, curl, imap, libcurl

using the code below and by using libcurl(curl library for C) I connect to the imap server of outlook with my login info and select the inbox folder and then I want to usse the FETCH command to fetch the entire body of a specific email and then save it to a file on the current directory but first I wanted to test the fetch command to see if it works correct so I tested it to fetch the subject of a specific email but the response is incomplete;
the response I get : `* 5 FETCH (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT) {27}` the expected response based on [text](https://www.atmail.com/blog/imap-commands/) :

```
* 5 FETCH (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)] {27}
Subject: Subject sample
 
)
```

and in some other commands the response is incomplete and in the same form; for example if I replace the command with `FETCH 5 (BODY[])` I get this response : `* 5 FETCH (BODY[] {44037}`

the code that Im working with (for the record it saves the response in a file named fetched_data.txt):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>


int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) {
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.gmail.com");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://outlook.office365.com");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, CURLUSESSL_ALL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 993);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "your_email_address");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "your_password");

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Login failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            return 1;
        }

        //const char *select_command = "SELECT \"[Gmail]/All Mail\"";
        const char *select_command = "SELECT Inbox";
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, select_command);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Selecting mailbox failed: %s (%d)\n", curl_easy_strerror(res), res);
        } else {
            printf("Mailbox selected successfully!\n");

            // Modify fetch_command to fetch the entire body of the email
            const char *fetch_command = "FETCH 5 (BODY[])";
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, fetch_command);

            // Create a file to save the fetched data
            FILE *file = fopen("fetched_data.txt", "wb");
            if (!file) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create file to save fetched data\n");
            } else {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, file);
               // curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

                if (res != CURLE_OK) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Fetching data failed: %s (%d)\n", curl_easy_strerror(res), res);
                } else {
                    printf("Data fetched and saved successfully!\n");
                }

                fclose(file);
            }
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

for the record I tried the with my gmail too and the results were the same and if you want to try with gmail just add the commented lines of code for the line that sets the imap server and for the line of the first command in the server which is SELECTing inbox(you cann add the commented code for the all mail folder of gmail or simply write SELECT INBOX)

Now can you tell why the fetch command is not working the way it should and how should I reach my ultimate goal of fetching the entire body of a specific email so that I can use it to parse it and find the attachment of it if there is one ?

UPDATE:
I realized(but not sure of the fact) that the number in the curly braces is the amount of bytes I need to read after the "}" meaning that number of bytes is the data I wanted to fetch but I dont know how to do that! I whould be glad if you help me if the solution is this way.

Comment: Facing the same issue here, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @CharleyWright 
yes you can take a look at the source code of below project of mine in my github page: https://github.com/KAZIcodes/Image-Processing-Project-with-Email-and-DownloadLink-input-using-C